# Random variable from pdf in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to simulate some random variables distributed as a Variance Gamma.

I know the pdf ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution ) but I don't know the inverse of the cumulative function F: so I can't generate a random uniform variable U and compute `x=F^(-1)(U).`
I have to do this in MATLAB.

Thank you!

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

The next natural alternative to look into is Von Neumann's "acceptance-rejection method".

If you can find a density `g` defined on the same space as your `f` such that

1. you know how to generate samples from `g`, and
2. f(x) <= cg(x), for some c, for all x,

then you are good to go.

If you search the literature, people *must* have done this. The VG is widely used in pricing options.

Answer (score -1):

Following @Drake 's idea: for the first step you can use Marsaglia and Tsang’s Method from [here](http://www.hongliangjie.com/2012/12/19/how-to-generate-gamma-random-variables/).

This is the code to generate gamma random numbers:

```
function x=gamrand(alpha,lambda)
% Gamma(alpha,lambda) generator using Marsaglia and Tsang method
% Algorithm 4.33
if alpha&gt;1
    d=alpha-1/3; c=1/sqrt(9*d); flag=1;
    while flag
        Z=randn;
        if Z&gt;-1/c
            V=(1+c*Z)^3; U=rand;
            flag=log(U)&gt;(0.5*Z^2+d-d*V+d*log(V));
        end
    end
    x=d*V/lambda;
else
    x=gamrand(alpha+1,lambda);
    x=x*rand^(1/alpha);
end
```

Comment: I'm talking about Variance Gamma distribution, not Gamma.. 
In MatLab the function gamrnd already exists